# Ubuntu 20.04 software center bug when using downloaded themes

Tags: gnome, software-center, themes, 20.04

I'm experiencing a bug when applying a custom theme downloaded from gnome-look.org.

This happens with most themes I've downloaded such as these:
<sub>https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1316887/

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1275087/

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1299514/</sub>

Here's the screenshot of the bug:

[image: Bug Screenshot]

As you can see, it's like the software center is skinless.

I've installed shell-extensions, gnome-tweaks, etc., and manually installed all those themes, copying them to `/usr/share/themes`. Also this does not happen with preloaded themes like Yaru, or Adwaita

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, snap packages and themes have issues, removing the snap pre-installed Ubuntu Software Center and installing gnome-software via apt-get was the answer, thank you very much